# How can I use a constant to call on something?

Tags: javascript

When I try to add a variable into a calling on a required value.
I am trying to input the constant cookieinfo in to calling on a cookie value.

```
const cookieinfo = "bot" + result.bot

const config = require('/Users/Owner/Downloads/RankBloxCode/config');
const bloxy = require('bloxy');
const robloxClient = new bloxy.Client({
    credentials: {
        cookie: config.cookieinfo
    }
});

//Input
result.bot = abc
//Output
output = config.botABC
```

Comment: Do you just want to export the constant and make it available via `require()`?

Comment: I have a value that I don't know but would be in the value result.info but I need to add the term bot Infront of it as that is how it is formatted in the config file.

Comment: So if `result.bot` is "ABC", you want the line to be `cookie: config.botABC`?

Comment: That is what I want.

Comment: Just use `cookie: config['bot' + result.bot]`

Comment: This is a dupe, but I can't find the question/canonical.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to find a question on that already made but I couldn't find one. My bad.

Comment: I don't blame you, I couldn't find it myself. It does exist though, there are just so many different ways people refer to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless I'm misunderstanding your problem, you must use bracket notation for dynamic keys (dot notation only works with static keys).

so `config.cookieinfo` has to be `config[cookieinfo]`

Comment: I simplified this by doing: cookie: config['bot' + result.bot]